# Flink temporal join not showing data

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I am trying to replicate the temporal join example on [Flink docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#temporal-joins), however no results are being showed. No errors either.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE currency_rates (
  `currency_code` STRING,
  `eur_rate` DECIMAL(6,4),
  `rate_time` TIMESTAMP(3) METADATA FROM 'timestamp',
  WATERMARK FOR `rate_time` AS rate_time - INTERVAL '15' SECONDS,
  PRIMARY KEY (currency_code) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',
  'topic' = 'currency_rates',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '<my-server>',
  'key.format' = 'raw',
  'value.format' = 'json'
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
  `id` STRING,
  `currency_code` STRING,
  `total` DECIMAL(10,2),
  `transaction_time` TIMESTAMP(3),
  WATERMARK FOR `transaction_time` AS transaction_time - INTERVAL '30' SECONDS
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  'topic' = 'transactions',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '<my-server>',
  'key.format' = 'raw',
  'key.fields' = 'id',
  'value.format' = 'json'
);
```

Inserts

```
INSERT into currency_rates 
VALUES ('EURO', 0.0139, TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-12 12:37:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));

INSERT into currency_rates 
VALUES ('CAD', 0.03101, TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-12 12:37:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));

INSERT into transactions 
VALUES ('001', 'EURO', 9.10, TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-12 12:50:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));

INSERT into transactions 
VALUES ('002', 'CAD', 5.20, TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-12 12:51:10', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));

INSERT into transactions 
VALUES ('003', 'EURO', 12.12, TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-12 12:52:10', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));

INSERT into transactions 
VALUES ('004', 'CAD', 13.13, TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-12 12:53:20', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));
```

Join query:

```
SELECT 
  t.id,
  t.total * c.eur_rate AS total_eur,
  t.total, 
  c.currency_code,
  t.transaction_time
FROM transactions t
JOIN currency_rates FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF t.transaction_time AS c
ON t.currency_code = c.currency_code;
```

No results are showed on the join query and I couldnt find any working sample out there.

What am I missing to get this temporal join to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has to do with the watermarks. A temporal join doesn't produce an updating/retraction stream, so it must wait for evidence that the currency_rates stream is complete up through the time of the first transaction before it can produce a final result for that transaction. (And so on, for the subsequent transactions.)

If you add

```sql
INSERT into currency_rates 
VALUES ('EURO', 0.0130, TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-12 13:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));
```

that should be enough to flush out some results.

If that doesn't solve the problem, then the [per-partition watermarking](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/table/kafka/#source-per-partition-watermarks) that some sources (including Kafka) use could be the problem. You can address this by either ensuring that every Kafka partition has some data, or by setting the [table-exec-source-idle-timeout](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/config/#table-exec-source-idle-timeout) configuration parameter so that the idle partitions don't hold back the watermark indefinitely.

For myself, I also had to add this property to the transactions table:

```
'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
```

Without this change to the table DDL I was getting an error. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70739865/2000823 for more info on this.)

These are the results I got from the temporal join:

```
id    eur_rate   total_eur    total   currency_code   transaction_time
001   0.0139     0.126490      9.10   EURO            2022-01-12 12:50:00.000
003   0.0139     0.168468     12.12   EURO            2022-01-12 12:52:10.000
002   0.0310     0.161200      5.20   CAD             2022-01-12 12:51:10.000
```

Comment: Still no results. I am running my tests on AWS Zeppelin, which has Flink 1.13. Would that be a problem?

Comment: If the parallelism of the job exceeds the number of Kafka partitions, that could cause the watermarks not to advance.

Comment: Checked the job and parallelism was set to 1, while my Kafka has 6 partitions. All of my coworkers are experienced the same, so we wonder if the docs sample actually works.

Comment: @TiagoBrenck I verified that I am able to get this to work, but only by making some changes -- see the update in my answer.

Comment: I included the scan mode, and same result. I inspected the flink job on Apache Flink Dashboard and under running jobs I can see the temporal join task. I can click on it and inspect the tab Watermark, and it returns this message: `No Watermark (Watermarks are only available if EventTime is used)`. This seems odd since I am using EventTime. Should I expect this Watermark tab to contain data? Or no result is the expected value?

Comment: You should see watermarks at the temporal join task; their absence confirms that lack of watermarks is the reason you aren't getting any results. Can you confirm that you see watermarks at the source task?

Comment: Source tasks shows `No Data` under watermark tag. I am investigating what could be missing, but would you know any configuration that I could add on the table creations?

Comment: David I got it fixed. I created the topics using the default params of my kafka, and the default partition for topics is 6. Since my inserts were too few to populate all the partitions, watermark was not getting set. An easy fix was to create new topics with 1 partition only. Could you please add this to your answer so others dont fall for the same trick?

Comment: Wish I'd realized that was the problem; very glad you figured it out. I've reworked my answer to include this.