# NoOffsetForPartitionException when using Flink SQL with Kafka-backed table

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-sql

This is my table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders (
  `id` STRING,
  `currency_code` STRING,
  `total` DECIMAL(10,2),
  `order_time` TIMESTAMP(3),
  WATERMARK FOR `order_time` AS order_time - INTERVAL '30' SECONDS
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  'topic' = 'orders',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
  'properties.group.id' = 'groupgroup',
  'value.format' = 'json'
);
```

I can insert into the table:

```sql
INSERT into orders 
VALUES ('001', 'EURO', 9.10, TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-12 12:50:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));
```

And I can have verified that the data is there:

```sh
$ kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic orders --from-beginning
{"id":"001","currency_code":"EURO","total":9.1,"order_time":"2022-01-12 12:50:00"}
```

But when I try to query the table I get an error:

```sh
Flink SQL> select * from orders;
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.NoOffsetForPartitionException: Undefined offset with no reset policy for partitions: [orders-0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value of `scan.startup.mode` is `group-offsets`, and there are no committed group offsets. You can fix this by setting `scan.startup.mode` to another value, e.g.,

```
'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
```

in the table definition, or by arranging to commit the offsets before making a query.

Flink will commit the offsets as part of checkpointing, but if you are using something like sql-client.sh or Zeppelin to experiment with Flink SQL interactively, setting `scan.startup.mode` to `earliest-offset` is a good solution.