# Flink Dynamic Tables Temporal Join - Calcite error

Tags: flink-streaming, flink-sql, dynamic-tables

I think I am doing exactly what was mentioned in this stack overflow question: [Flink temporal join not showing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70688670/flink-temporal-join-not-showing-data) and what has been mentioned in the [official doc](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#temporal-joins) to join two data streams with a temporal join but I keep getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.calcite.LogicalWatermarkAssigner cannot be cast to org.apache.calcite.rel.core.TableScan
```

while executing the following SQL:

```
SELECT v.rid, u.name, v.parsed_timestamp FROM VEHICLES v JOIN USERS FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF v.parsed_timestamp AS u ON v.userID = u.userID;
```

[image]

I have two dynamic tables that must be joined (regular join is not enough since I need to maintain the rowtime column from VEHICLES for further processing and lookup join is not okay since both sources come from Kafka).

The two tables were created with:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (
 userID BIGINT,
 name STRING,
 ts STRING,
 parsed_timestamp AS TO_TIMESTAMP(ts),
 WATERMARK FOR parsed_timestamp AS parsed_timestamp - INTERVAL '5' SECONDS,
 PRIMARY KEY(userID) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
'connector' = 'kafka',
'topic' = 'USERS',
'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka:9092',
'properties.group.id' = 'testGroup4',
'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
'format' = 'json'
);

CREATE TABLE VEHICLES (
 userID BIGINT, 
 rid BIGINT, 
 type STRING, 
 manufacturer STRING, 
 model STRING, 
 plate STRING, 
 status STRING, 
 ts STRING,
 parsed_timestamp AS TO_TIMESTAMP(ts),
 WATERMARK FOR parsed_timestamp AS parsed_timestamp - INTERVAL '5' SECONDS
) WITH (
'connector' = 'kafka',
'topic' = 'VEHICLES',
'properties.group.id' = 'mytestgroup4',
'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka:9092',
'format' ='json'
);
```

Any suggestion on what I have done wrong? I couldn't find that much information about the error.  If possible I would prefer to do not create the [views](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/table/concepts/versioned_tables/) and work directly with the two tables (and I have tried with the views but I still get the same message).

Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem is your use of a computed column as an event time attribute. Perhaps that's not supported.

Comment: I tried to create the column from metadata with TIMESTAMP(3) METADATA FROM 'timestamp' but I get the following error:
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.ParseException: Encountered "METADATA" at line 4, column 34.